# how to refresh pardot API key every hour automatically

Tags: apex, rest-api, pardot

I am making callout to PARDOT and displaying prospect data into VF page, the issue is every one hour api_key get expired and I have to manually make a authentication call to pardot to get the api_key. Is there any way through which I can automate this process ?

Here is my authentication method in the rest service.

```
public void AuthToPardot() {    
        String email = 'test@gmail.com';
        String password = 'test';
        String userKey = 'testuserkey';

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint( 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/4' );
        req.setMethod( 'POST' );
        req.setBody( 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password + '&user_key=' + userKey );

        HttpResponse res = new Http().send( req );

        String response = res.getBody();
        Integer startIdx = response.indexOf( '<api_key>' ) + 9;
        Integer endIdx = response.indexOf( '</api_key>' );
        String apiKey = response.substring( startIdx, endIdx );
        System.debug('******'+apiKey );// I am getting value here
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visualforce, you can just use an action poller:

```
<apex:actionPoller interval="3600" action="{!authToPardot}" reRender="page" />
```

This snippet here sets up a 3,600 second timer to call the AuthToPardot function, and reRender an element with the id of "page" (this is optional, but avoids refreshing the entire page, so it looks nicer).